# need to replace < symbol with &lt from an xml at particular node using xslt

Tags: xslt

### INPUT

"hi all i need an xslt to replace < symbol to &lt: in the particular node of an xml, how can i achieve this."

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:adm="http://axn/someurl/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <adm:Access>
     <String1> <log item='value' price='fixed'/></String1>
     <String2><US/></String2>
  </adm:Access>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### OUTPUT

"this is wat finally i need. replcing < with < at node0 and node1.i need to replace only "<" but not ">" symbol"

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:axn="http://axn/someurl/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <axn:Access>
  <node0>&lt;log item='value' price="fixed"  /></node0>
  <node1>&lt;US /></node1>
  </axn:Access>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

"have tried to parse the content of node0 and node1 as text with and replace but it dint work"

Comment: I am a bit confused by what is part of the question text and what is exemplary string data here.

Comment: using string.replace() in xslt1.0

Comment: I don't understand, either -- why do you want to encode the opening `<`, but not the closing `>`?

Comment: @ABach it's only `<` and `&` that _must_ be escaped.  You _may_ escape `>` as `&gt;` but it's still well-formed if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, using XSLT, to **replace** the `<` symbol. XSLT provides access to the values inside markup (e.g. element names) and to the markup payload - not to the markup itself (other than by way of copy).

What you *can* do is output some **text** using the above values - see for example:
[Converting XML to escaped text in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162352/converting-xml-to-escaped-text-in-xslt)
[How do I Emit Escaped XML representation of a Node in my XSLT's HTML Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638367/how-do-i-emit-escaped-xml-representation-of-a-node-in-my-xslts-html-output)